# post time don't change in loop - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a simple loop to get latest five posts, which only consist of post title and time i wrote the loop below and the title generates fine, however the time doesn't change. as it get the first post in the loop's time for other posts as well. so all the post time is same.

Please advise why time don't loop ?

```html
<?php
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
   $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
   foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ ?>

                 
                     <li class="orbit-slide">
                        <div>
                           <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>" class="ticker-a">
                              <span><?php echo get_the_time($recent["g:i a"]); ?>  &nbsp;</span>
                              <?php echo $recent["post_title"]; ?>
                           </a>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                     

 

 <?php  }
   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Aruns answer should work. This is because you are iterating through an array rather than using the standard wordpress while loop functions, so you have to pass the post ID in to the get_the_time function for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks "Aron" for answer 1 :

```html
echo get_the_time('', $recent["ID"]);
```

And Thanks "WizardCoder" for the other loop solution:

```html
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'orderby' => 'most_recent' );
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
  <li class="orbit-slide">
    <div>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ticker-a">
        <span><?php the_time("g:i a"); ?>  &nbsp;</span>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
<?php
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
echo get_the_time('', $recent["ID"]);
```

Comment: check your post time in backend

Comment: How to do that, sorry i'm new here  :)

Answer (score 0):

On a side note. This is a much more efficient piece of code and it is easier to output content.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'orderby' => 'most_recent' );
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
  <li class="orbit-slide">
    <div>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ticker-a">
        <span><?php the_time("g:i a"); ?>  &nbsp;</span>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
<?php
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Agreed, but i got as a result 10 posts in the loop. even-though the numberposts = 5

Comment: Sorry I have edited my suggestion. I used `numberposts` instead of `posts_per_page`.